# EXCEL: Search column for multiple strings, and give cell(s) of mismatch(es)

Tags: excel, text, position, excel-formula, mismatch

I want to search into an entire column for mismatches (type-errors I made) compared to the available types I've defined. And in case there are any mismatches I want to have the cell of that mismatch displayed in the cell below.

So this is what I have (I replaced the actual types with synonyms for privacy reasons, obviously they aren't named type# irl):

**Column E : E**

- type1   (E1)
- type5   (E2)
- type3   (E3)
- type3   (E4)
- type7   (E5)
- ***tipe2***   (E6)
- type9   (E7)
- (E8)
- type3   (E9)

**Column K2 : K10**

- type1   (K2)
- type2   (K3)
- type3   (K4)
- type4   (K5)
- type5   (K6)
- type6   (K7)
- type7   (K8)
- type8   (K9)
- type9   (K10)

For example puposes I made the type-error "tipe2" in cell E6 and also added an empty row in cell E8.
Now I want a formula which displays "Error" when something in column E:E does not match one of the types in column K2:K10, and else print either nothing or "no error found".
And at the same time I want in a seperate cell the coordinates (in this case E6) of the mismatching cell.

I've already got the part to get the mismatching cell, where my_string should be replaced with the mismatching string that has been found:

```
="E"&MATCH("my_string",E:E,FALSE)+IF(COUNTIF(E:E,"my_string")=1,0,COUNTIF(E:E,"my_string")-1)
```

PS: I don't want a VBA script! I just want formulas inside two cells. One to see wether or not I made a mismatch, and incase I did made a mismatch I want the Cell's coordinates (or the last Cell's when multiple mismatches are found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a so-called array formula to achieve this. As an illustration, I simulated your situation in this image:

[image: Excel picture of situation]

The important cell is `H1`, which contains the index of the offending cell in column `E`. For the sake of simplicity, I introduced two named ranges `items`, containing cells `E1:E9` and `lookup` containing cells `K2:K10`. The formula in `H1` is

```
=MAX(IF(ISBLANK(items),0,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(items,lookup,0)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(items))),0)))
```

This is an array formula, which means that you have to confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you did that right, the formula will show curly brackets around it -- you do not type those yourself. This formula goes over all cells in the range called `items`, creates an array with the value 0 for all cells that are blank or that have a match in the range called `lookup`. For the remaining cells, the value inserted is equal to the row number. Then the maximum is taken over that.

As a result, `H1` will contain the index of the last offending item. If all items are OK, then the value 0 is displayed.

Cell `G1` shows `Error` if any offending item has been found, and `OK` otherwise. The formula is

```
=IF(H1=0,"OK","Error")
```

Finally, `I1` displays the actual offending item via

```
=IF(H1>0,INDEX(items,H1),"")
```

If you do not want to use the named ranges, then replace `items` with `$E$1:$E$9` and `lookup` with `$K$2:$K$10`.

If the offending cell is an empty cell, then `I1` will contain the value 0.

I think the value in `H1` is useful for analysis, but if you do not want it, you can hide it. Or you can fold that formula in the ones used in `G1` and `I1`, but the formulas become pretty complicated.

A workbook containing this answer is uploaded [here](http://temp-share.com/show/dPf3LyuHW)

As a note on the side: are you aware that you can use Excel's data validation feature with a drop-down list to avoid these kinds of typos you are looking at. That might be useful for you. An example is given in the article [Drop-Down Using Data Validation in Microsoft Excel](http://www.officearticles.com/excel/drop-down_using_data_validation_in_microsoft_excel.htm)

Comment: This already looks great! But is it somehow possible to exclude empty cells from giving an error with the MATCH-formula, so it won't give a #N/A error when the cell is empty, but does give #N/A when a type-error is made. I know there is the ISEMPTY-formula, but I don't know exactly how to fit it in your formula from cell H1.

Comment: The adjusted formula in `H1` now allows blank cells, they will not cause "Error" to be displayed. Some extra explanation about how the formula works is given. I slightly improved the formula in `I1` as well to remain blank in case of no error. Finally, I added a remark on data validation. Hope this helps.

Comment: The uploaded example file reflects the latest answer as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and the dropdown is indeed a lot easier to just aviod those typos.

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way to do this is; to use the filter "Does not contain"

Excel 2010 solution, similar for 2003

- Select the whole column
- Select Data
- Select Filter
- Select filter option (triangle at top of column)
- Select text filters
- Select Does not contain
- Enter type
- Modify and rerun as needed.

Comment: Thanks, thats already a huge step in the right direction, and I can indeed check the entire column for type-errors I made. Though I would still like the first Formula so I know when I have made a mismatch and need to check the filter. Since I add quite a lot to the table each day it would make it easier for me then just check the filter each day.